# Video lag/pixelation in Safari

Tags: html, video, safari, html5-video

I am uploading .mp4, .webm, .ogv, .swf files to our servers for video playback. We are using the code below for cross-browser/fallbacks.

```
<video width="570" height="338" tabindex="0" loop="loop" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="/Resources/videos/product.mp4"></source>
  <source type="video/webm" src="/Resources/videos/product.webmsd.webm"></source>
  <source type="video/ogg" src="/Resources/videos/product.oggtheora.ogv"></source>
  <object width="570" height="338" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/Resources/videos/product.swf">
    <param wmode="opaque" value="/Resources/videos/product.swf" name="movie">
    <param value="false" name="allowFullScreen">
    <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
    <param value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.com',{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.com%2FResources%2Fvideos%2Fproduct.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" name="flashVars">
  </object>
</video>
```

The videos work flawless in IE, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (windows). However the video lags and is pixelated in Safari on Mac. See image below:[image]

I am wondering if anyone has come across this issue before and could steer me in the right direction to fix it. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `<object>` and all `<sources>` except the one for Safari?